# Unable to keep a fixed size of collectionview cell when adding constraint to it's subview i.e. a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal collection view that contains an UILabel. I have mentioned the collection view cell's size in the delegate method.

[image]

And added leading, trailing, height and vertical center constraints to that label as shown in the below image.

[image]

[image]

But in the output, the width of the label is getting increased or decreased based on the text and the collection view cell size as well.

[image]

[image]

I want to keep the size of the collection view cell fixed as mentioned in the delegate method.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, it sounds like you might be adding a width constraint to the label that’s equal to the label’s text width. That width constraint will force the cell to expand to meet the requirements of the leading, trailing and now width constraints. Instead, make the width constraint equal to the width the label should be.

Second, set the label’s .numberOfRows property to 0. This will make it so the label will break into multiple horizontal lines instead of going wider.

Edit:
Another thing that could help might be to adjust the `horizontalCompressionResistance` property on the label to 249 or something lower.

Comment: I think it's the opposite? There is no width constraint set, so the label will expand and the cell will expand along with it. By setting a width constraint, the label will be forced to a certain size, so the cell will be the forced to be the size of the label plus leading and trailing margins.

Comment: That’s true, I explained that incorrectly. I meant you shouldn’t have a width constraint that’s equal to the label’s width. You could have a width constraint but it would have to be a set value based on the cell’s width. I’ve updated the answer to reflect that